# Five points concyclic on cyclic pentagon

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I am looking for a solution of the problem as follows:

Let $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5$ be a cyclic pentagon, let $B_i=A_{i-1}A_{i} \cap A_{i+1}A_{i+2}$ for $i=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, here we take modulo $5$. Let $(O_i)$ is circle through $B_i, A_{i+2}, A_{i+4}$. Let $C_i=O_{i+1} \cap O_{i+4}$ then show that $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5$ lie on a circle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this theorem is called [Takada's theorem (高田の定理)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%AB%98%E7%94%B0%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86), and was first discovered in 1989 by Hideyuki Takada, a then high school student, and proved by Tominosuke Otsuki and Kazuo Masuda. You can see their proofs in [Tominosuke Otsuki and
Kazuo Masuda, "CERTAIN THEOREMS ON PENTAGONS."](https://tus.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=1556&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=21)

Here is another elementary proof.
[image: appended figure]

Let $\mathcal{P_1}=\odot{(A_1A_2C_1)}$ and $\mathcal{P_5}=\odot{(A_5A_1C_5)}$. Let $D_1$ be the second intersection of $\mathcal{P_1}$ and $\mathcal{P_5}$, different from $A_1$.

Observe that
$$\begin{align}\measuredangle{A_1D_1A_2} & =\measuredangle{A_1C_1A_2}\\ & =\measuredangle{A_1C_1A_4}+\measuredangle{A_4C_1A_2}\\ & =\measuredangle{A_1B_2A_4}+\measuredangle{A_4B_5A_2}\\ & =\measuredangle{B_3A_4A_3}\end{align}$$
Likewise, $\measuredangle{A_5D_1A_1}=\measuredangle{A_4A_3B_3}$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align}\measuredangle{A_5D_1A_2} & =\measuredangle{A_5D_1A_1}+\measuredangle{A_1D_1A_2}\\ & =\measuredangle{A_4A_3B_3}+\measuredangle{B_3A_4A_3}\\ & =\measuredangle{A_5B_3A_2}\end{align}$$
This implies that $A_2$, $B_3$, $A_5$, $D_1$ are concyclic, i.e. $D_1\in (O_3)$. Let $E_2$ be the second intersection of $\mathcal{P_1}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{A_2A_3}$, different from $A_2$. Let $E_9$ be the second intersection of $\mathcal{P_5}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{A_4A_5}$, different from $A_5$. By applying [a converse of Miquel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miquel%27s_theorem#A_converse_of_Miquel%27s_theorem) to $(O_3)$, $\mathcal{P_1}$, and $\mathcal{P_5}$, we get that $E_2$, $A_1$, $E_9$ are collinear. Hence,
$$\begin{align}\measuredangle{E_9E_2A_3} & = \measuredangle{A_1C_1A_2}\\ & =\measuredangle{B_3A_4A_3}\\ & =\measuredangle{E_9A_4A_3}\end{align}$$
So we find that $E_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$, $E_9$ are concyclic. Furthermore, we have
$$\begin{align}\measuredangle{A_4C_1E_2} & =\measuredangle{A_4C_1A_2}+\measuredangle{A_2C_1E_2}\\ & =\measuredangle{A_4B_5A_2}+\measuredangle{A_2A_1E_2}\\ & =\measuredangle{E_9B_5A_1}+\measuredangle{B_5A_1E_9}\\ & =\measuredangle{A_5E_9A_1}\\ & =\measuredangle{A_4A_3E_2}\end{align}$$
Thus, $C_1$, $E_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$ are concyclic. Similarly, $E_9$, $C_5$, $A_3$, $A_4$ are concyclic. Therefore, $C_1$, $E_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$, $E_9$, $C_5$ lie on a common circle. Denote this circle by $\mathcal{Q_1}$. Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the circle $\odot{(A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5)}$. By applying [Miquel's six circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miquel%27s_theorem#Miquel%27s_six_circle_theorem) to $(O_1)$, $(O_3)$, $(O_5)$, $\mathcal{Q_1}$ and $\mathcal{R}$, we can see that $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_4$, $C_5$ are concyclic. With similar
arguments, $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_5$, $C_1$ are concyclic, and we are done. $\square$

There is another remarkable theorem in this configuration: construct the radical line of $(O_{i})$ and $(O_{i+1})$ (indices are taken $\bmod 5$). Then these five radical lines meet in a point. This holds true for any pentagon $A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5$. It is often called [the five-circle incidence theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/math.mag.87.1.44) and attributed to Larry Hoehn. Seemingly this theorem was re-discovered by Tran Quang Hung; the point of concurrency is listed as [5G-s-P5 1st 5G-Hung’s Point](https://chrisvantienhoven.nl/ng-items/5g-obj/5g-pts/5g-s-p5) in the Encyclopedia of Polygon Geometry.

I found an interesting property about this configuration: the two circles $\odot{(A_1B_2B_4)}$ and $\odot{(A_1C_1C_5)}$ are tangent to each other at $A_1$.